# Fullpage.js disable autoscroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

**I am pretty new at the coding, just so you know.**

I am using the Fullpage.js for my portfolio, and its working great..
But i want to disable the autoscroll when the site is shown on a mobile device.
I have searched a lot, and found some answers but dont know where to put them/adjust them, so i never got it to work sadly.. 
When i change **autoScrolling: true, - to autoScrolling: false,** it works fine, but i only wont it to be false on a mobile device.

Can anybody help me? I haven't learned much about Js btw.

Comment: I found this code; var isPhoneDevice = [ WHATEVER FUNCTION YOU WANT TO USE ]

//if it is not a phone device...
if(!isPhoneDevice){
    //initializing fullpage...
    $.fn.fullpage();
}

Comment: So there you go.. Use your `autoScrolling` init function in there ?

Comment: or even better, use `autoScrolling: !isPhoneDevice()` ?

Comment: So i just have to put autoscrolling: false into the [ WHATEVER FUNCTION YOU WANT TO USE ]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a mobile phone for you? Why only on a mobile phone and not in a small viewport?

Usually the approach nowadays is to style the website based on the dimensions of the screen/viewport and not in the type of device.

You should be using the `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight` options provided by fullpage.js.

Comment: Well it is a small viewport in my eyes, i just got used to say mobile, tablet or desktop. the Responsivewidth does not have anything to with the autoscroll, does it?

Comment: Erm.... it does?? Read [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js): *responsiveWidth: (default 0) A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used under the defined width in pixels. A class fp-responsive is added to the body tag in case the user wants to use it for his own responsive CSS. For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's width is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.*

Comment: AHH! I see that now, it makes more sense. Now my only problem is, how do i write this into my js correctly?

Comment: As right now, i have this; 

     var isTouch = "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement; 
            $(document).ready(function() {
        if(isPhoneDevice){
            autoScrolling: false,
        };
            else{
                //desktop               
                $.fn.fullpage();
            }
        });

Comment: Check [the demo online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html). The source code is available in [the fullpage.js example files](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples) that come with the download.

Comment: I have already checked it out the demo before i downloaded it. there isnt a source code for the autoscroll:false for mobile devices, as far as i can see.. But thanks a lot.